# What does an empty return in Python mean?

Tags: python

When looking through Python code on GitHub, I've seen several examples of a `return` with no value. For example:

```
    if hasattr(self, 'moved_away'):
        return
    # and here code continues
```

What does the empty return mean?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It means it will `return None`. You could remove the `return` and it would still return `None` because all functions that don't specify a return value in python will by default  return `None`.

In this particular case it means the code will go no further if the object has the attribute `'moved_away'`, without the return  any code below would be evaluated even if the `if` statement evaluated to True.

So you can think of it as being similar to a break statement in a loop when you have a condition you want to exit the loop on, without the break the code would continue to be evaluated.

```
if hasattr(self, 'moved_away'): # if this is True we return/end the function
        return
     # if previous statement was False we start executing code from here
```

Answer (score 9):

`return` exits the current function.

So, here it will stop the execution & return `None`.