# Function is returning type None when I expect an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to returning an array that has been passed through a recursive function. But I'm only getting back None, instead of the `bo` Numpy array which I expected.

```
import numpy as np

board = [0, 0, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
         4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 2, 0,
         0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 6]

grid = np.asarray(board).reshape(9, 9)


def possible(bo, y, x, n):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if bo[y][i] == n:
            return False
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if bo[i][x] == n:
            return False
    x0 = (x // 3) * 3
    y0 = (y // 3) * 3
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            if bo[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n:
                return False
    return True


def solve(bo):
    for y in range(9):  # row
        for x in range(9):  # column
            if bo[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range(1, 10):
                    if possible(bo, y, x, n):
                        bo[y][x] = n
                        solve(bo)
                        bo[y][x] = 0
                return
    return bo

solved = solve(grid)
print(solved)
```

Why is this?

I can print it out to the console. But the return value is `None`.

Just to note, the first `return` statement exits out of the recursive function. Allowing to move onto subsequent items in the array.

(Previous question was marked as duplicate - but the linked question didn't answer my query)

Edit: To make it clear what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to return the modified `bo` array. The first `return` statement exits out of the recursive `for n in range` statement. And then runs through with another # in the range.

Comment: Your first `return` statement of the function `solve()` should return something explicit. Take a look at the control flow options [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: Does `solve` modify `grid`  as expected?

Comment: Yes. The code functions but won't return. I can print it out by typing `print(bo)` inplace of the return at the end of the function `solve`. But it comes out as `None` when I try to return the `bo` object.

Comment: I suggest that you put a print() above both returns so you can see for yourself which return is the final one.

Comment: The final return is the last one in `solve`. It prints out the expected result. but returns `None` when I try to return it.

Comment: Replace the `return` line with `return 'foobar'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does an empty return in Python mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340634/what-does-an-empty-return-in-python-mean)

Answer (score 1):

If I change the bare `return` line to:

```
 return 'foobar'
```

the result is:

```
In [5]: grid = np.asarray(board).reshape(9, 9)                                                                       
In [6]: solve(grid) 
Out[6]: 'foobar'
```

A bare `return` is the same as `return None` (as is falling off the end of the function).

Even if the function is recursive, and modifies `bo` (and `grid` after running it has the right values), the function returns on that condition, not the final `return bo` line.

So

```
return bo
```

in both places returns the modified `grid`.

```
def solve(bo):  
    for y in range(9):  # row  
        for x in range(9):  # column  
            if bo[y][x] == 0:  
                for n in range(1, 10):  
                    if possible(bo, y, x, n):  
                        bo[y][x] = n  
                        solve(bo)           # doesn't use the return value  
                        bo[y][x] = 0  
                return bo       # final return 
    return # bo optional
```

Within the recursion you count on `bo` being modified, and never use the returned value.  That's why with `solve(grid)`, `grid` is changed.  If you want `solve` to return the modfied `grid` you have to return it explicitly.

In code like this, you need to pay close attention to all `return` statements, and be aware of which is returning when.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in your `return` statement in your `solve(bo)` function.

```
for n in range(1, 10):
    if possible(bo, y, x, n):
        bo[y][x] = n
        solve(bo)
        bo[y][x] = 0
return
```

Whenever your function finishes this loop, it will always return `None` because it has a return, but isn't returning anything.

Comment: The `return` statement exits the recursive loop. Without that return, it doesn't function as expected.

Comment: You can replace the `return` with a `break` statement because it will exit the loop without returning a value.

Comment: I tried that. But it doesn't return a fully modified array.